# Forward pages onto holding page then onto relevant page on new site

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, forward

I have an old website that is being replaced (`www.old.com`) and a new website that's replacing it, and which has similar pages (`www.new.com`). I need all the pages within `www.old.com` to automatically redirect to a holding page (simple html page with the below countdown script and redirect function)... However, the challenge is that I then need the redirect to go to the relevant page on `www.new.com.`

**code:**

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
        var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
        div.textContent = count;
        if (count <= 0) {
            window.location.href="https://example.com";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

For example... **www.old.com/about/** shows the holding page and countdown timer, then forwards to **www.new.com/about-us/**.

Comment: Use something like `RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "http://www.new.com/$1"` in `htaccess`

Comment: Yes, but that rewrite rule will just forward a page on old.com to new.com - there won't be a holding page with a countdown in the middle...

Comment: Well if you want to go from `www.old.com/about/` to `www.new.com/about-us/`, then you need to have at least the information that `about` has now become `about-us` stored _somewhere_, because obviously your machine can not simply “guess” that ... So, tell us where you have stored this info as of now …?

Comment: That's what I'm asking... How can I have a holding page show *before* redirect when the slugs may not be identical. My initial thought was www.old.com/about forwards to www.old.com#/about (which shows holding page at index.html, then redirects to www.new.com/about-us, mapped based on what is after # in the previous url. But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

**To redirect only single page**

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage http://www.mysite.co.uk/newsubdir/newpage?
```

**To redirect whole website permanently to other domain**

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new.com/
```

It's really important to implement a proper 301 redirect for any pages which change URL, so that the Google bot has an easy time understanding that the page has permanently moved location.

Google will then update it's index to point through specifically to the new page, and any inbound links and other signals will be attributed to the new page (usually allowing you to keep high rankings in Google search results provided all the content is still on the page, and that it's still properly optimised on-page (i.e. meta title tags, description, text copy on the page etc)).

**NOTE :**

This will not redirect email for your domain

Answer (score 0):

Make a little modification to your Javascript code, such as

```
<script>

    var old = window.location;
    old = old.replace('http://www.old.com', '');
    var newLocation = "https://example.com" + old;

    setInterval(function() {
        var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
        var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
        div.textContent = count;
        if (count <= 0) {
            window.location.href = newLocation ;
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

This will redirect your page as you expected.